# "to wherever" is grammatically correct?

Tags: usage

In the sentence

> We follow God to wherever He is leading us.

doesn't "to" have to be deleted since wherever means at any place where and already includes preposition in itself?

Comment: Informally, I think "to" is fine, and maybe even sounds better, because it emphasizes that we are following him **to** a place, as opposed to just following him at whatever place he happens to be in right now.

Answer (score 2):

As is often the case, both versions are correct but mean subtly different things.

> We follow God to wherever He is leading us.

Here, "to" implies reaching a place. God is leading us to some place and we follow him until he gets us there.

> We follow God wherever He is leading us.

This means that, whenever we are in a place where God is leading us, we follow. But it might be that we get to some place where we don't feel he's leading us any more, so we stop following. The lack of "to" implies that we're describing where the following takes place, rather than what the goal of the leading and following is.

Answer (score 0):

Your sentence

> We follow God to wherever He is leading us.

can be expressed as

> [Wherever He leads I'll go](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zk5qhaJTURI&t=0m50s)
>   We follow God wherever He leads us.

The preposition "to" is not necessary for understanding this sentence.
Whether we are being led **to** salvation or **from** temptation, your sentence is saying "we will follow".